# MST-Kruskal Algorithm with two types of weight

Tags: algorithm, graph

TL,DR: When growing an MST, in the case where there are many Lightweight edges to choose from, how do I choose a specific one to add to the MST?

I have a generic question, I've been trying to solve the entire day, but reading my algorithms book & searching the web didn't help me out. I cannot share my code, because it's for a university project and it's basically the only scenario I am missing out.

Imagine the following problem.

I have a graph with N edges and I want to find it's MST (the typical problem). However, apart from having edges which have the cost of connecting vertex u to vertex v, those same vertices may have a special flag, that allows them to connect to all other edges with that same special flag.

I answered this problem, by creating one special vertex, to which all vertices with that flag connect to, with the respective cost.

Everything works fine. The problem arises when the MST has many possible solutions. I should output one that uses the least amount of special flag connections.

I know it may be hard for readers to make suggestions without seeing my code. But unfortunatly, I really can't share.

What I can say is that I am defining an Edge, regardless of it being special or not as a structure {u, v, cost}

One thing I tryed, was sorting the Edge Vector by crescent order of weight as requested by the standart kruskal algorithm, but whenever the weight is the same push the edge that is a "special edge" forward into the vector.

So I would have something like this
[cost 1 normal, cost 1 normal, cost 1 special, cost 2, cost 3, cost 3 special, ...].

Any ideias?

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are explaining seems to be on the right lines, but here is another way of looking at the problem.

When building an MST, you only have to compare the costs associated with edges - your code doesn't have to do anything very sophisticated with costs.

So the costs don't have to be ordinary numbers. They could have two components, one used for the usual comparisons, and one used as a tie-break when the first component compares equal. Another way of looking at this is to say that all the costs look a bit like 123.000000000000000000000456 where there are so many zeros between the first part of the cost and the second part of the cost that the second part of the cost is never relevant in a comparison unless the first part is equal, and there is never any sort of carry from the second part up to the first part.

So in your problem, the first part of the cost would be the ordinary weight of an edge, and the second part of the cost would be 1 if it is a special edge and 0 otherwise. In this case the minimum cost would be the minimum ordinary cost, with the number of special edges used as a tie-breaker.